# Why component variables initialized via [(ngModel)] still have null values?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng, angular-ngmodel

I am working on an Angular application and I have the following problem.

Into a reactive form I have defined these two fields:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <p>Prezzo fattura</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10">
    <p-inputNumber id="invoice_cost" formControlName="invoice_cost"  [(ngModel)]="invoiceCostNg"
                   mode="currency" currency="EUR" locale="de-DE"
                   [disabled]="!isEditAssetDetails">
    </p-inputNumber>
      
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <p>Franchigia</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10">
    <p-inputNumber id="deductible" formControlName="deductible" [(ngModel)]="deductibleNg"
                   mode="currency" currency="EUR" locale="de-DE"
                   [disabled]="!isEditAssetDetails"
                   (onInput)="calculateDeprecation($event)">
    </p-inputNumber>                         
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see both these form fields have **[(ngModel)]** linked to the following TypeScript component code variables **invoiceCostNg** and **deductibleNg**.

Into my TypeScript component code I have done something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-asset-details',
  templateUrl: './asset-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asset-details.component.scss']
})
export class AssetDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    invoiceCostNg: number = null;
    deductibleNg: number = null;
    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    
    public calculateDeprecation(value) {

        let startingValue = this.assetDetailsForm.value.invoice_cost;
        let deductible = this.assetDetailsForm.value.deductible;

        console.log("INVOICE COST: ", this.invoiceCostNg);
        console.log("DEDUCTIBLE: ", this.deductibleNg);
    }
}
```

As you can see changing the value into the second input field this it is called the **calculateDeprecation()** method that have to use both the **this.invoiceCostNg** and the **this.deductibleNg** fields (the ones bounded via the **[(ngModel)]** attribute).

The problem is that when this method is executed this is the obtained output into the Chrome console:

```
INVOICE COST:  null      asset-details.component.ts:432 
DEDUCTIBLE:    null      asset-details.component.ts:432
```

Basically it seems to me that the **[(ngModel)]** attribute doesn't fill the related component variables.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: Interpolate those vars into view and see if they changes as you type.

Comment: Mixing `formControlName` with `ngModel`? That will not work.

Comment: `ngModel` it's for template-driven form if you are using Reactive Forms you should use `FormGroup` and `FormControl`. You should check [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for reactive forms and [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms) for template-driven forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use (ngModelChange) to check value that ngModel emit
2. I think the problem comes from output (onInput)
3. 

- Same as 1, you can use (ngModelChange) to handle event deductibleNg change
- Use reactive form

```
FormGroup.get('deductible').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
// handle logic here
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Define like this:
invoiceCostNg: any;
deductibleNg: any;
By default angular takes as variable initial value as "undefined".
Here you have defined default value as null that's why you are getting null in console.
And why have you used both ngModel and formControlName?

Comment: I tried to define nvoiceCostNg: any; deductibleNg: any; but I am obtaining the same issue. I also have to define as formControlName because it is also used for form values update